# Searchbutton click event

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

When I press enter it works great. However I also want to perform search by clicking the searchbutton in the text box. I added `oncommand` attribute, it performed the search however after search ended, searchbutton changed into a cross. I clicked the cross it performed the search again. I checked the documentation however could not find any information about how to associate my searchbutton click with search event.

```xul
    <textbox id="txt1" type="search" searchbutton="true" editable="true"
    onkeypress="keyHandler(event);" />
```

Comment: You can perform this in many ways!! please post your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a side-note: Do not process clicks or key presses directly, always use the `command` event - this makes sure the behavior of the element is consistent with what the user expects.

`<textbox type="search">` assumes that performing the same search twice makes no sense. So after performing the search the search button changes into a cross, clicking that cross *clears* the search text (and triggers a new `command` event of course). If instead of clicking the cross you change the search text you will get the usual search button again. So your `command` handler should look at the search text: show default results if the text is empty (search text cleared either manually or by pressing the cross) and perform a new search if the text is non-empty.

Comment: This is the answer that I needed, however I cannot associate the `command` with `searchbutton`.

Comment: @Ghokun: You don't have to, a `command` event on the `<textbox>` element will be triggered automatically for all the relevant cases - including the user clicking the search button.

Comment: I checked again, searchbutton fires the command but I do not get relevant results. I guess my search function needs some tweaking. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is mayn't corresponding to your problem but this will give an idea to finsh your task.

XUL Textbox:

```
<textbox id="textbox" type="search" oncommand="SearchKeyword(this)"/>
```

Js:

```
function SearchKeyword(oElem) // Function for search for the characters
        {
         var filter = document.getElementById("textbox");
         filter.setAttribute("value", oElem.value);
         document.getElementById("myTodoListTree").builder.rebuild();
      }
```